# Determine if Windows Store App has been suspended or tombstoned from Windows Service

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, windows-store-apps

I have an application switcher in Windows 8.1 which enumerates all top level windows (EnumWindows in user32). Unfortunately this call will include suspended and tombstoned Windows Store Applications. I can detect when a process is suspended by checking if all threads are suspended and waitreason is also suspended. I can however not see any difference between if they have been suspended or tombstoned and I would, like ALT-TAB, show the suspended apps but not the tombstoned ones. I have also tried to see any differences between these processes in Process Explorer without success.

TLDR;

Is there any way that I could, from a Windows Service or Desktop application, query a process to see if it is tombstoned (and not just suspended)?

Answer (score 2):

When a Windows Store app is terminated because the system needs to free resources--which is what I assume you mean by tombstoned--then it's process is removed entirely (that is, they disappear from Task Manager).

To differentiate between apps that are suspended and those that have been "closed" using Alt+F4, the close button, or the swipe-down gesture, call IsWindowVisible on the handle you get back from EnumWindows. If it's false, then the app has been tombstoned; if it's still true, then the app is just suspended.

Comment: When closing a Windows Store App by pressing ALT-F4, drag and dropping it to the bottom of the screen or press the close button in Windows 8.1 update 1 will all lead to a state where it no longer shows up in Task bar (8.1 update 1) nor ALT-TAB. The process is still running though it is suspended. I thought it was in a tombstoned state but I'm not sure. I can however not from any api's I've found query the process and see if it has been "closed" or merely suspended due to no longer being shown on screen.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't know the answer but will check into it.

Comment: The answer is to call IsWindowVisible on the window handle; a tombstoned app will have this set to false, but a suspended app will still be true. I've updated the original answer here accordingly.

Comment: I'm afraid tombstoned apps still has a valid window handle. Reproducable by opening Bing Maps and close either by dragging it to bottom om screen or clicking close button. Disappears from ALT-TAB and Task bar but process is still running (but suspended) and the main window handle is still valid.